# UIActionSheet Tinting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, tint

Anyone know anyway to tint uiactionsheet in uikit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, because it's an UIView (as described by kmit) you can use the following commands:
addSubview, thereby you can add your own background and order it back with sendSubviewToBack. (you can delete the old background by this: [[youralert.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview])

Comment: [[actionsheet.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview]; removes the first button on the action sheet and objectAtIndex:1 removes the second button and so on

Comment: there are only 3 subviews which are the three buttons

Comment: aha actually yeh the addSubview: and sendSubviewToBack: works a beauty :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too. Here is a code snippet that I used (sorry I can't use formatting in a comment): 

<code>UIView *greenView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
greenView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
greenView.alpha = 0.25;
[sheet addSubview:greenView];
[sheet sendSubviewToBack:greenView];</code>